# Send IPC message from main process to renderer process Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

Currently I have an Electron menu with a save button on it. When this save button is pressed I wish to send an event to the renderer process, for the renderer to handle the event.

Here is what I have attempted:

**Menu Source**

```js
const menuTemplate = [
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [
            {
                label: "Save",
                accelerator: "Ctrl+S",
                click: () => {
                    BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().webContents.send("save");
                }
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

**Renderer Source**

```js
ipc.on("save", () => {
    console.log("save");
})
```

**Preload source**

```js
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from "electron";

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipc", { on: ipcRenderer.on });
```

When trying this I get no output whatsoever when pressing the save button, including no errors. I can confirm that the correct menu is being utilised by Electron and that the `click()` function is executing. I can also confirm that `ipc.on` is indeed defined in the renderer.

How can I get this working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you define `ipc` in the renderer?

Comment: In the `preload.js`, I have now edited the post to show the preload source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `this` manually in the on function.

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipc", { on: ipcRenderer.on.bind(ipcRenderer) });
```

or make a new function that passes the args:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipc", { on(event, fn) { ipcRenderer.on(event, fn) } });
```